# Changing out of stock text on variable products

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm creating a Wordpress website with Woocommerce and am using variable products. I know how to change the out of stock text for the variants of the product, but I would like to know how to change the out of stock text when I have no variants added at all (i.e. set the product type to variable product and add no variants).

As it stands, the text that is shown by default is: "This product is currently out of stock and unavailable."

How would I go about changing that text?

[image: Demonstration]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really easy to achieve this with the gettext filter.

```
function modify_gettext( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.' :
            $translated_text = __( 'This is my new out of stock text', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'modify_gettext', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: Cheers Andrew! Works Perfectly!

Comment: You can use this filter for pretty much all text in WordPress and WooCommerce.  You're welcome.

Comment: What does "woocommerce" in line 4 stand for?
And "20" and "3" in the last line

Comment: @SaidAssassi https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the dedicated WC filter hook `woocommerce_get_availability` this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_specific_out_of_stock_availability', 20, 1 );
function change_specific_out_of_stock_availability( $availability ) {
    $targeted_text = ('This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce');

    if( $availability['class'] == 'out-of-stock' && $availability['availability'] == $targeted_text )
        $availability['availability'] = __('Custom "Out of stock" notice', 'woocommerce');

    return $availability;
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

That message uses the **woocommerce_out_of_stock_message** hook.
You can add a filter for it:

```
function custom_woocommerce_out_of_stock_message()
{
    return __('This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce');
}
add_filter('woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', 'custom_woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', 10);
```

and just change the text.